# How to set React Native background location for accurate result? Can only be done in Native?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, geolocation

I'm trying to create a running app with React Native. The background location permission needs to be in "Allow all the time" to get an accurate location when the screen is off (in addition to turning the power saver and battery optimization off).

How can run apps like "Strava" and "Runtastic" be able to track background location accurately only with "While only using the app" permission?

I have been researching and testing for 5 days now with no luck. Even using paid background module (react native) required "Allow all the time" permission to get accurate results: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation.

Is this can only be done in native? If yes, can I integrate the background native code to react native?

Would appreciate any guidance.

Thank you.